Vue 3 Generic Components: how to use a scoped slot with a generic data type inferred from an event listener prop
Click for Playground
<SideSheet>
  <template #activator="{ onClick, ...slotProps }">
    <v-btn
      v-bind="slotProps"
      @click="(e: PointerEvent) => onClick(e, { id: 5, piece: {id: 4, name: 'something' } })"
      class="text-none"
      variant="plain"
      text="Click me"
    ></v-btn>
  </template>
   <template #default="{ initialData, onClose }">
    <div class="flex-fill d-flex flex-column justify-space-between h-100">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column ga-3">
        {{ JSON.stringify(initialData) }}
      </div>

      <v-btn variant="flat" color="#160616" @click="onClose()">
        Close
      </v-btn>
    </div>
  </template>
</SideSheet>

Basically I have a side sheet component where I can use a custom component for the default slot which gets access to some initialData passed via the second parameter of the onClick event listener prop of the activator slot.
I would like initialData to be typed inside the default slot via the T generic used in the onClick function, but it doesn't work.
Even if it's not possible to dynamically infer T from onClick I would still be happy to know how to manually type the generic from the vue template. Something like:
<SideSheet<IData>>

which is obviously not a valid Vue template syntax.

I consider this an hack but it's the only workaround I've found to hint the generic type without being forced to create a ref for initialData:
<v-bottom-sheet v-model="toggle" initial-data-type="initialDataType">
[...]
defineProps<{ initialDataType?: T }>()

<SideSheet :initial-data-type="{} as IData">

